# unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, kubernetes, jenkins

I am installing  running Jenkins in  EKS ( Amazon Kubernetes) , I am trying to integrate Jenkins with AD credentials . For this I am preparing a jks file and passing it to JAVA_OPTS as below , but its giving me error unable to find  valid certification path to requested target, even though the certificate is available at that path. can any one able to help me .
Thanks in Advance .

**I am giving JAVA_OPTS as below**

```
JAVA_OPTS: -Dcasc.reload.token=$(POD_NAME) -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/jenkins_keystore/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

The file keystore.jks file exists .
[image]

```
 hudson.util.Retrier#start: The attempt #1 to do the action check updates server failed with an allowed exception:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:122)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:219)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:214)
    at hudson.PluginManager.checkUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1951)
    at hudson.util.Retrier.start(Retrier.java:62)
    at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1922)
    at jenkins.DailyCheck.execute(DailyCheck.java:93)
    at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork.lambda$doRun$1(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:102)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```